# How to stop yup validation on disabled fields?

Tags: javascript, validation, formik, yup

I have the following:

1. two fields: **department** and **clinic**
2. two radio buttons **department** and **clinic**

   If the clinic radio button is checked, then the department is disabled.
   Now I want yup to validate the clinic field only when it is enabled. I tried something like this

```js
// Clinic:
Yup.string().when('isDisabled', {
  is: false, 
  then: Yup.string.required('clinic required')
})
```

Answer (score 13):

Set three fields, for example, `department`, `clinic` and **`kind`** . The **`kind`** field is the name for radio buttons

Then set the value of each radio button like `department` and `clinic`, and your validation schema like this:

```js
validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  kind: Yup.string().required(),
  clinic: Yup.string().when("kind", {
    is: (val) => val === "clinic",
    then: Yup.string().required(‘clinic required’),
    otherwise: Yup.string().notRequired()
  }),
  department: Yup.string().when("kind", {
    is: (val) => val === "department",
    then: Yup.string().required(‘department required’),
    otherwise: Yup.string().notRequired()
  }),
})
```

Comment: you are the best (:

Answer (score 2):

```
const object = {
  name: 'Foo',
  hiddenOnMobileField: 'Boo'
}

// you can use any condition attribute (Ex: isMobile)
export const validationSchema = (isMobile) => yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().trim().required('name is required'),
  // this field disabled on a mobile
  hiddenOnMobileField: yup.string()
    // use empty array
    .when([], {
      // any condition to remove validation
      is: () => !isMobile,
      then: yup.string().trim().required('hiddenOnMobileField is required'),
      otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
  })
})


validationSchema(true).validate(object, { abortEarly: false })
  .then(...)
  .catch(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method :

Two Fields :

1. department ---> Boolean
2. clinic ----> String

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  department: Yup.boolean(),
  clinic: Yup.string().test(
    "conditionalRequired",
    "Field is required",
    function (value) {
      const { department } = this.parent;
      if (department === true) {
        return !!value;
      }
      return true;
    }
  ),
});
```

Here yup will validate the **clinic field** only when **department** is enabled.